# $n$th derivative of function

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

> Let $f(x)=x^{2015}e^{1/x}$ for $x\neq 0$. How to find $2015$-th derivative of $f$?

I tried to use formula $(f(x)g(x))^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}f^{(k)}(x)g^{(n-k)}(x)$, but it seems that closed formula cannot be obtained.
Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try the $n$th derivative of $f(x)=x^{n}e^{\frac{1}{x}}$ for $n=1,2,3,4$ and factor out $\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x^n}$.  You should be able to see permutation coefficients

Comment: Generalizing the hint from @Henry - when there's a seemingly random large number like $n=2015$ is a problem statement you should start by calculating for the first few values of $n$.